# Android onTextChanged for two EditTexts, do I use an array?

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext

I have 2 editText's and I want to handle both inputs with onTextChanged, can I do this with an array if so how, I dont see how I can do it without using arrays. OK, this is the update on what I have.

```
    public class AlphaActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TO_BOX = "TO_BOX";
private static final String FROM_BOX = "FROM_BOX";
//  private String updateGuess;
//  private String update_label;

private int guess, theFirst, theLast;
//private int count;

private String update_text;

EditText firstText;
EditText secondText;

TextView updateLabel;

Button tooHighButton;
Button tooLowButton;
Button correctButton;
Button newGameButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alpha);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        // Just started
        theFirst = 0;
        theLast = 100; 
    } 
    else
    {
        // App is being restored
        theFirst = savedInstanceState.getInt(TO_BOX);
        theLast = savedInstanceState.getInt(FROM_BOX); 
    }

    //fromBox   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstText);
    //toBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondText);

    //fromBox.addTextChangedListener(fromBox);
    //toBox.addTextChangedListener(toBox);


    updateLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.updateText);

    firstText   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstText);
    firstText.addTextChangedListener(fromBoxListener);

    secondText  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondText);
    secondText.addTextChangedListener(fromBoxListener);

    tooHighButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.guiTooHigh);
    tooLowButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tooLowGui);
    correctButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.correctGui);

    setButtonOnClickListeners();

}



private TextWatcher fromBoxListener = new TextWatcher()
{

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            //theFirst = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            theFirst = Integer.parseInt(firstText.getText().toString());
            theLast = Integer.parseInt(secondText.getText().toString());

            if (theFirst > theLast)
            {
                updateLabel.setText("You must flip your integers"); 
            }
            else if (theFirst < 0)
            {
                updateLabel.setText("You cannot enter a negative number!"); 

            }

            guess = (theFirst + theLast) / 2;
            updateLabel.setText("Did you think of " + guess + " ?");

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            updateLabel.setText("You must enter an integer! ");
        }

        //updateLabel();

    }

};



private void setButtonOnClickListeners(){

    tooHighButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            theLast = (guess - 1);
            guess = (theFirst + theLast) / 2;

            if (theFirst < theLast)
            {
                secondText.setText("" + theLast);
                updateLabel.setText("Did you think of " + guess + " ?");
                //count++;
            } else if (theFirst > theLast)
            {
                updateLabel.setText("It appears you changed your number!");
            } else
            {
                updateLabel.setText("Did you think of " + guess + " ?");
            }



        }
    });

    tooLowButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            theFirst = (guess + 1);
            guess = (theFirst + theLast) / 2;

            if (theFirst < theLast)
            {
                firstText.setText("" + theFirst);
                updateLabel.setText("Did you think of " + guess + " ?");
                //count++;
            } else if (theFirst > theLast)
            {
                updateLabel.setText("It appears you changed your number!");
            } else
            {
                updateLabel.setText("Did you think of " + guess + " ?");
            }   

        }       
    });


    correctButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            updateLabel.setText("Thank you for playing this game!");
        }

    });

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.alpha, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What would you use the `Array` for? I'm confused on exactly where your problem is. Setting the textChangedListener?

Comment: I want to detect two editText boxes. How can I do that when I have one "s"    
will it still work like this? theFirst = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            theLast = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

Comment: Set your `TextWatcher` on both like you would any other `Listener`. I haven't done it that way for a `TextChangedListener` but I would try that

Comment: So I need two separate textwatchers?

Comment: what if I need to use both theFirst and theLast?

Comment: No, try to set this TextWatcher on both of them with `addTextChangedListener()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what I think you are asking you can do the following,

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(fromBoxListener)
editText2.addTextChangedListener(fromBoxListener)
```

Now, the code in

```
 @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

will run when the text in either of them has changed. I'm not sure if this is what you really want since I don't know how your logic works or what you are trying to accomplish in the end.

Also, since you are parsing an Object that could have non-integers, you may want to wrap it in a `try/catch` or do some type of error-checking

Comment: i am doing exactly what you are telling me to do, but it doesn't work

Comment: Be more specific. What about it doesn't work? Do you get errors? If so, post the logcat into your question

Comment: ok i just updated what I currently have. I want to update a label based on the two EditText's

Comment: I don't have any errors, its just not working how I expect it to work, it seems as if the textWatcher is not even detecting the editBoxes

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint inside `onTextChanged()` to see if it enters the method when you enter text? Also, the way you have it `updateLabel` is always going to be the same because of `updateLabel.setText("Did you think of " + guess + " ?");`

Comment: OK this is the problem, I just updated what I have now, and I want the user to press the enter (TextWatcher) and then the label to pop up and say "Did you guess of 50?" then the user will either say too high, too low, or correct. However, when I enter the numbers in my emulator and then press enter, the label does not say anything, but I want it to update it with a guess

Comment: For example, I am currently using the ranges 0 and 100 and it should give me, "Did you guess of 50?". However, it does nothing, but when I click on too high, or too low, it says, "It appears as if you have changed your number" which makes sense. I know my logic is right, I have this running on my GUI with Java, I am just trying to transfer it to ANDROID. thank you

Comment: Ok this actually works fine, but now the app crashes whenever I press a button? Any ideas?

Comment: Not without knowing what the error is. But this is a separate issue so you really should accept one of the answers that helped with this problem and post a new question with relevant code and logcat. If you do I will be happy to give it a look. I would check that your names for buttons are spelled correctly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your code to the `afterTextChanged()` method of your `TextWatcher`?

External listeners get updated before the internal `Editor` of an `EditText` during the `onTextChanged()` phase, so your readings for `firstText.getText()` and `secondText.getText()` may not return the results you expect because they haven't been internally updated yet.